# Simplify HTML code with local reference

Tags: angular

I am building a form with angular 2. The following code does work.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
    <label 
      class="errorMessage" 
      *ngIf="!this.registrationForm.controls['firstName'].valid" 
      for="firstName">
      First name is required</label>
  </div>
```

I wanted to simplify it abit so that I dont have to do

```
!this.registrationForm.controls['firstName']
```

I thought I could assign a local reference to the input field like the following to reduce the code. However it does not work for me

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" #firstName>
    <label 
      class="errorMessage" 
      *ngIf="!firstName.valid" 
      for="firstName">
      First name is required</label>
  </div>
```

Is this is not the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Drop `this` as echonax mentioned. Also `get()` is the preferred way of accessing controls.

```
*ngIf="!registrationForm.get('firstName').valid"
```

You can also add a getter

```
get firstName() : AbstractControl {
  return this.registrationForm.get('firstName');
}
```

or assign the control to a variable even before you added it to `FormBuilder` for binding purposes.